# How to handle off-topic questions on the new First questions review queue?

Tags: discussion

I noticed that the *First Posts* review has been replaced by *First Answers* and *First Questions* reviews. I've reviewed a handful of first questions to see what the new queue is about.

For on-topic questions the default review action choices (*Looks OK, Edit, Share feedback*) are ok I think, but I'm a little puzzled what to do with off-topic posts. Sure, I can click *Flag* and pick a suitable reason for a close vote, but then what?

**Share Feedback?**

I find the suboptions (*Question is unclear, Question is too broad*) a bit lacking. They might be good for some posts, but for questions regarding for example 3rd party plugins I don't think they're a good fit.

**Edit?**

I don't think any amount of editing will make a generic PHP/HTML/JS/CSS questions or a question about 3rd code on-topic.

**Looks OK?**

The option's description says, *"This question can be understood and answered as-is (be sure to vote accordingly)."* The [help center description](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/review-first-questions) says, *"Choose Looks OK if the post requires no intervention."*. Off-topic question can usually be understood, but require an intervention (closing) - it's ok, while not being ok. So.. yes?

**Skip?**

Or should I just let it be someone else's headache?

Comment: The system has changed.  You now have "*Other Action*".  So it is possible to flag the post, then click Other Action to indicate none of the above actions are relevant.

Comment: @Chenmunka Sweet, and the Close action seems to be back too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The help center article says:

> Sometimes a question will need to be closed, which can be done by flagging or voting to close it.

But there is no close vote option, which is probably a bug. So you have to flag it as "needs improvement", and from there you can select one of the regular close reasons.

To be honest, the UI doesn't look finished to me. Casting a close vote shouldn't require a flag.

Update: This is one of the many [known bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release). I guess it will be addressed soon.

Second update: This has been resolved now, the close button is available again.

Comment: Yes, I took me couple of tries to figure out that the close vote could be found under the "needs improvement" option. I miss the "close" and "I'm done" options the First posts review had.